# Success on getting metadata except GPS information

Tags: objective-c, gps, metadata, avfoundation

I'm using this code to extract metadata when taken a picture with AVFoundation.

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(resizedImage, 0.8f);

CGImageSourceRef imageData2 = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)imageData, NULL);
NSDictionary *metadata = (NSDictionary *) CFBridgingRelease(CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageData2, 0, NULL));

NSDictionary *exifGPSDictionary = [[metadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary]mutableCopy];

NSLog(@"exif gps dict : %@", [exifGPSDictionary objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude]);
```

Except GPS section is missing. I do get exif, tiff etc all that but GPS.
In plenty of questions answered on SO, everyone claims to get full result including GPS.(latitude/longitude of the spot where the picture was taken)
However I do not and would love to know why.

Please someone answer this question..!